# Custom sorting option with filter doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, I added those filters listed below for new products sorting option in Woocommerce - by sort status. It works well without any other query parameters `?orderby=abailability` but when I add filter to the query it shows no results
(`?orderby=availability&type=some_custom_type`)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    $orderByValue = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean($_GET['orderby']) : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));
    if ('availability' === $orderByValue) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_stock_status';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby($sortBy) {
    $sortBy['availability'] = 'Availability';

    return $sortBy;
}
```

What am I missing here?